# The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect. SQLSTATE=22007

Tags: db2, informatica

Am facing Issue with date format while running Informatica mapping with database db2.

Effective date coming from input is "2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000000".

But on passing to stored procedure I called in mapping it is reading it in format **"03/17/2020 00:00:00.000000000"** which causes Informatica to throw the following exception into the Informatica session logs.

```
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
ERROR   4/2/2020 11:53:34 AM    ecrmqetl    TRANSF_1_1_1    CMN_1022    Database driver error...

CMN_1022 [ [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007  sqlstate = 22007

Database driver error...
Function Name : ExecuteSP

Native error code = -180
Database driver error...
Function Name : ExecuteSP

Native error code = -180]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Wrong Timstamp <-> String conversion probably. Provide more details with **exact data types and values** on how this parameter is passed to the routine and how it is used there in the failing statement.

Comment: Cannot tell from your question exactly how your mapping is supplying the effective-date to the stored procedure. If your mapping is converting the literal string '2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000000' into the string '"03/17/2020 00:00:00.000000000' then your mapping is broken.  If the Db2-stored-procedure parameter datatype is TIMESTAMP then once again, your mapping should be converting from string to timestamp value correctly. Note that currently supported versions of Db2 on AIX will correctly handle the string "2020-03-17 00:00:00.000000000" and be able to convert this to a timestamp datatype.

Comment: read it as string and then convert it like this to_date ( substr(date_str_col,1,20),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS').

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert input string into expected date type format .